# How can I make my menu align correctly on all media devices

Tags: css, responsive-design, alignment, media-queries

I have an wordpress website, my menu on certain devices aligns perfectly and on others it displays the menu button underneath the logo on my page. It is a responsive website.

I want my menu button to align properly on all devices IOS and Android ....

This is the code that was given to me that allowed the menu to align correctly on (certain devices)

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) {
 .section-navi .navi-container {
min-height: 50px;
padding-right: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: left;
}
```

To see what i am referring to go to: surveillanceshack.com on a mobile device